# Mysql Workbench 8 doesn't detect the my.ini file for my MySql 5.7 server. How can I point it to the correct file?

Tags: mysql-5.7, mysql-workbench, my.ini

I upgraded MySql workbench to version 8.
I'm running MySql Server 5.7.
When I open the options file in workbench it says it cannot locate a file for MySql 8 and that it will create one in the path `C:\ProgramData\MySql\MySql Server 8\my.ini`
I do not have MySql Server 8 installed.

- Why is workbench not finding the file?
- How can I point it towards the correct file?
- Do I need to downgrade workbench?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Workbench tries to find the config file at a common location. If there's none then it will create it, when you edit the configuration and save it (and only then).

However, you can set the ini location in your connection details. For that open the connection editor (e.g. by right clicking on a connection tile on the home screen and selecting "Edit Connection...". Once the dialog is open switch to the "System Profile" tab. On this page you will find places where you can set an own config file path and even the config file section, if that differs from the default ("[mysqld]").